# Highcharts ignore skipped dates

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working on a heat map with a lot of dates, but I've now removed weekends from the data. Unfortunately, that had the side effect of adding blanks to the heat map.

I've tried the connecting nulls option to no avail: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.connectNulls

Also tried: showEmpty:false

And I'm aware of https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time, but don't know if I can apply that here.

Here is a pic:
[image: heatmap]
Ideally I would figure this out because I intend on thinning out the data further. For example I may remove every other day.

Here is the pertinent chart code:

```
{

 ...

 xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
  align: 'left',
  x: 5,
  y: 14,
  format: '{value:%B}'
 },
 tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
},
series: [{
  boostThreshold: 100,
  borderWidth: 0,
  nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
  colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
  tooltip: {
   headerFormat: '<b>Details</b><br/>',
   pointFormat: 'Date: {point.x:%A, %b %e, %Y}<br/>Underlying Price: ${point.y}<br/>Positon Value:{point.positionvalue}<br/>NET:{point.net}<br/>ROI:{point.roi}%'
   },
   turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
  }]

...

  app.chart.config["series"][0]["data"] = chartData;
```

The chartData variable looks something like:

```
[{
 net: -0.2
 positionvalue: -0.54
 roi: -30.3
 value: -30.3
 x: 1591329600000
 y: 55
}]
```

If you need to see it in prod I can attach my url.

UPDATE:
Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vo8syrhn/

Comment: Try a normal xAxis without type:’datetime’

Comment: I tried omitting the xAxis, which would default it to linear. No go.

Comment: Do not omit the xAxis. Just omit type.  See answer below:

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only solution for this case is use the `breaks` feature. Notice that using it requires including the `broken-axis` module.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t72dfwz9/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: Very cool. My reasoning for skipping dates was mostly to make it easier/quicker for highcharts to render. Adding these breaks seems like it would take just as long, or potentially longer to compute/render. I have not done speed tests, just guessing.

Comment: @ToddHorst Hard to say - depends on your data. I have seen in your demo that you have attached the boost module - it should help to render your chart quicker. Doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: It is fast enough, was just looking to make sure it stays that way

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to omit the xAxis.type. You can see a demo on jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/r32z7esd/ (note data for 2020-06-05 is missing)

html code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="chart">
</div>
```

js

```
Highcharts.chart("chart", {
        title: {
            text: "chartTitle" 
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2020-06-06','2020-06-04','2020-06-03'] 
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: "yAxis1Title"
            }
      }],
      series: [{type:'column',data:[3,4,7]}]
    });
```

Comment: I should have done a fiddle to begin with. I updated the question with a fiddle now. Omitting type will default it to linear, which produces the same result. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: I got your point. I tried different things with highcharts and could not achieve what you want. It seems you will have to extend the heatmap chart type - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts